# **SOLVED** Right head lamp full beam not working

Tags: electrical, land-rover

**SOLVED**

Any help appreciated!!

Both head lights are working as normal when on low beam. The moment I switch to high beam the left headlight goes to full and the right lamp goes out entirely. I've swapped the bulbs and the issue remains with the right head lamp.

I have driving lights attached to the right lamp and these no longer work either.

Many thanks in advance for any help,

Ben

Comment: Check all the wires / connections on the right hand headlight.

Comment: I've checked all the wires and they're all intact and working as far as I can tell. Could it be a circuit breaker or fuse or something?

Comment: Could be many things, check from either end for supply, broken wires, blown fuse etc But be logical and don't jump about - that's how you miss something.

Comment: Main fuse was fine but fuse for individual light under the steering wheel had blown. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of editing your question with "solved" write your own answer with the information, then when you can, select it with the check mark to close the question ok n and actually let people know that way there is an answer which worked. That's how Stack Exchange works!

Answer (score 1):

I would check all the wires that connect right headlight, then if there is nothing wrong, maybe see a electrical mechanic...

Comment: I've checked them as far as I can and they seem to be working. Could it be a circuit breaker or fuse?

Comment: Maybe, check them too.

Comment: It was an individual fuse under the steering wheel! Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ben, you can answer your own question below!